# Split screen in Cloud9 IDE

Tags: cloud9-ide

Is it possible to have a horizontal split screen (that is, two files open, one on the left, one on the right at the same time) in Cloud9? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: Cloud9 now allows splitting multiple and individual files now in many ways and options. Just right-click on any tab and select one of the split pane options, or "Duplicate View" if you want to split the current file. Similar options exist in the "View" menu.

Answer (score 4):

Cloud9 does not have split screen yet. We are currently working on the next iteration of the IDE client, which will have a powerful split screen feature.

Comment: Is your new beta version of Cloud9 going to be available via the github project? The beta looks awesome, btw..

Comment: The new version of Cloud9 (released mid 2014) now has split screen mode.

Answer (score 3):

Just wanted to point out that it seems possible to do this in the local version of cloud9 I have running - just shift click on open tabs as per this thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cloud9-ide/YdOcUecXYYo

Comment: Unfortunately that only works for a single file, not two different files :(

Comment: Shift-clicking open tabs definitely works for two different files for me locally, but it might not be available on the hosted version.